# Too much [cakephp-*]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I feel that we have too many `cakephp-*` tags.

[cakephp-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.0) or [cakephp-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-3.0) or [cakephp-1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-1.3) or [cakephp-2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.3) or [cakephp-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.1) or [cakephp-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-3.x) or [cakephp-appmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-appmodel) or [cakephp-2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.4) or [cakephp-1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-1.2) or [cakephp-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.2) or [cakephp-2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.5) or [cakephp-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.x) or [cakephp-3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-3.2) or [cakephp-3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-3.4) or [cakephp-2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.6) or [cakephp-bake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-bake) or [cakephp-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-3.1) or [cakephp-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.7) or [cakephp-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-model) or [cakephp-3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-3.3)

[cakephp-appmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-appmodel) and [cakephp-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-model) have almost the same excerpt even.

Does it seem like tag soup here?

Comment: What? The masses have no breadphp-*? Well, [let them eat cakephp-*!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_them_eat_cake) We have plenty!

Comment: [CakePHP has been under some discussion on meta earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cakephp+%5Btags%5D+).

Comment: I'm not an SME but unless those minor versions all are hugely different and unless anyone wanting to answer cakephp-3.4 never wants to see cakephp-3.1 I would say all those version tags can be synonym in their cakephp-2.x or cakephp-3.x

Comment: @rene exactly my feelings

Comment: Seems to be standard practice for other frameworks such as Rails.

Comment: In [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278529/7795130), the question and answer were expressing the need to have very well defined cakephp-1.x, cakephp-2.x and cakephp-3.x . The second answer goes really indepth into what versions have backwards compatibility and what versions do not.

Comment: As I understand the second answer from the link I just shared, we only need the 1, 2, and 3 tags, anything more specific is overkill.

Comment: @DavyM In that post, I said "15 (that's hyperbole) different CakePHP tags." Little did I know...

Comment: @rene I'm not a Small- or Medium-sized Enterprise either. Uh, what's an SME, in this context?

Comment: This applies to a lot of frameworks / languages but I don't think there is a consensus on this. On one hand, if you use only the very specific tags, you won't have much view due to people following the global tags (most of the time), on the other hand, if you use a two generic tag, you get answers that do not work with your version.

Comment: @MarkAmery Subject Matter Expert

Comment: The cake is real, for once.

Comment: It would be nice if SO had a feature for tags where you could define a version (if needed) when you ask a question.

Comment: Just like PHP or anything else just [cakephp] and then state your version in the question.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Not that searchable. This is such a common thing that it might worth the feature request. Versions would be unified and easy to find UI-wise for every question.

Comment: At least it has relatively normal version numbers. I still occasionally have flashbacks to the "just call it angular now, not angular4" thing making it impossible to find documentation or tutorials...

Comment: Why don't you sort them by version number? [tag:cakephp-1.2] [tag:cakephp-1.3] [tag:cakephp-2.0] [tag:cakephp-2.1] [tag:cakephp-2.2] [tag:cakephp-2.3] [tag:cakephp-2.4] [tag:cakephp-2.5] [tag:cakephp-2.6] [tag:cakephp-2.7] [tag:cakephp-2.x] [tag:cakephp-3.0] [tag:cakephp-3.1] [tag:cakephp-3.2] [tag:cakephp-3.3] [tag:cakephp-3.4] [tag:cakephp-3.x] [tag:cakephp-appmodel] [tag:cakephp-bake] [tag:cakephp-model]

Comment: You know what, that sounds like an acronym that everybody could be using anywhere, IANASME. Why is this the first time I heard of it? Why is this not incredibly widespread?

Comment: @MrLister Acronym usage? IWLTH, but IANASME.

Comment: This is a general issue with software following SemVer. We've (had?) the same issue with Symfony, where version 3.0 has no new features to the last 2.x version (2.8). For many questions, it really doesn't matter if the question is about Symfony 2.3 or even 4.1. If the exact version is really necessary to answer the question, it should be part of the question (not as a tag).